# Kubernetes set a timeout limit on image pulls

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I’m getting `Failed to pull image` because the image pull is timing out, I know the image is there I just think my private registry is slow, is there a way to set a timeout limit on image pulls?

Answer (score 6):

The timeout limit can be controlled with the `--runtime-request-timeout` option for the `kubelet` service.

[Official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet/) for this:

> Timeout of all runtime requests except long running request - pull, logs, exec and attach. When timeout exceeded, kubelet will cancel the request, throw out an error and retry later. Default: 2m0s (default 2m0s)

Even though this is not really visible from the description, this value is still passed down into the [RemoteImageService (see source code an Github)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/5e442a3f61e1e1eb67323183cfba6540c02a4a54/pkg/kubelet/kubelet.go#L276) which is used to pull the images.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank's for the help, it there a way to put this in my deployment manifest? I'm deploying using helm not kubelet.

Comment: There's no configuration available to do this through the API anyhow. This has to be configured per node/kubelet. Sorry

Comment: Doesn't the doc say "Timeout of all runtime requests except long running request - pull"? Isn't this specifically saying it doesn't apply to pull requests?